# Boolean Algebra simplify minterms

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I need to simplify this minterns equation with theorems  and I'm really stucked (like stucked for real something like 3 hours),

**F = A' B' C' D' + A' B' C D' + A' B C D' + A B' C' D' + A B' C D + A B C' D + A B C D' + A B C D**

Thanks for helping me, good evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Here are some principles that will help you simplify:

**Adjacency**

$PQ+PQ'=P$

(for example, in your case you can combine the first two terms into $A'B'D'$ and the last two terms into $ABC$)

**Absorption**

$P + PQ=P$  (The $P$ term 'absorbs the $PQ$ term)

**Reduction**

$P+P'Q=P+Q$  (given $P$, the $P'Q$ term 'reduces' to $Q$)

**Distribution**

$P(Q+R) = PQ+PR$

**Consensus**

$PQR+PQ'=PR+PQ$$

Note that Consensus is a combination of Reduction and Distribution:

$PQR+PQ'=P(QR+Q') = P(R+Q')=PR+PQ'$

but it's useful to be able to do this in 1 step.

(for example, after you have combined the first two terms to $A'B'D'$, you can do Consensus with the third term to reduce the third term to $A'CD'$, and also use $A'B'D'$ to do Consensus with the fourth term to reduce that fourth term to $B'C'D'$. Likewise, after you have combined the last two terms to $ABC$, you can apply Consensus to reduce the fifth term to $ACD$ and the sixth term to $ABD$)

Comment: @VujadinJokic Sounds good. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @VujadinJokic OK, I applied a bunch of Adjacencies, and that seems to make it as simple as you can get.

Comment: @VujadinJokic Yes, that's one of several ways to simplify it.  There are several possible answers, but they all have five times three terms. So good job!

Comment: @VujadinJokic Hey, I have something to do right now ... Maybe later ... But I am sur you can find them yourselves as well, just by trying other combinations for Adjacency.